Alerta si el usuario va a salir de página
Quisiera un evento que se ejecute mostrando una alerta cuando el usuario intente salir de una página. Pero, de todas las maneras, es decir:

si sale de la vista a otra
si recarga
si cierra el navegador.

He visto que hay paginas que te suelta una alerta, de si estas seguro de salir, algo así quisiera

¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask]

La verdad no he intentado nada, pero me imagine, que de existir la posibilidad, sería como un evento simple de JS que es independiente del resto de código, para activar el evento antes de salir, no se si existe otra manera.

Te comparto algunas publicaciones relacionadas: Ejemplo 1 y Ejemplo 2

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

El evento beforeunload es el que lanza la ventana de confirmación para salir. Y tiene al menos 3 limitantes:

El usuario debe haber interactuado con la página por ejemplo haber hecho un click, muy parecido a lo que ocurre con el sonido de los videos donde también ese necesario interactuar con la página para poder activarlo

Según la documentación, no es confiable en dispositivos móviles

No puedes cambiar el mensaje de alerta, eso lo pone el navegador a su gusto


Demo:


window.addEventListener("beforeunload", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = true;
});
<a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>



